# vs2019 .net core project CopyToOutputDirectory is invalid

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

1. Create .net core wpf custom controls project
   [image]
2. Setting .csproj
   [image]
3. Packaging .net core project
4. Create wpf .net framework 4.6.2 project
5. Reference .net core project package
   [image]
6. Running wpf .net framework project none content files
   [image]

Comment: Do I get you right: you want these file to be both compiled as resource and copied to the output? May I ask why?

Comment: no,i want only copied to the output

Comment: `packaging .net core project` using which settings? Have you added any settings to instruct the *new* project to copy the content files to the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CopyToOutputDirectory` option is not applied in consuming projects. If you want a content file to be copied to the output directory of a consuming project, set the `PackageCopyToOutput` to `true`.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Include="Themes\Metro\Contents\Dropper.ico">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
   </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```